# ExtJS: Maintaining state of the components using URL

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am working on a single page ExtJS application. The problem with the application is that whenever the user refreshes the screen, it goes back to its initial state. What is required is that whatever components were opened shall remain opened. For example, if I am working on a window and refreshes the screen it should open that window again. What should be the steps to achieve this?

What my initial thought is that if I can manage to add the component's(in this case window) id or something else to the URL(for example www.example.com/index.html!#windowservices) on click of a button and then on page load get that component opened using the URL(!#windowservices). Is this possible? Can the URL be modified(even if I have to make a fake ajax call)? Can someone point me to any example where the URL is modified and kept in the history of the browser?

Comment: Thanks Saki. Looks like http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#route-mvvm is the answer. Will ask you more when needed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things, both already having some infrastructure in Ext, you could/should exploit: state and routing. State helps to keep things like window size and position, sorting order of grid or similar persistent. Routing helps you to navigate into a particular screen of the application directly from the url. See the Sencha docs and http://extjs.eu/examples for more information and examples and/or keep asking here as needed.

Answer (score 0):

But why are you wanting to do this control manually?
AngularJS avoid you to need worry about that, just inject ngRoute in your app, define your routes and the magic happens...

AngularJS:
https://angularjs.org/

ngRoute:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Getting start with routes and templating:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Built with AngularJS:
https://builtwith.angularjs.org/

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but the application is a pure ExtJS single page application. Can't add AngularJS to it. Also, the same thing can be achieved by ExtJS routing. I wasn't aware but I think it is sufficient enough for me. Thanks again.